# does ofstream::close() call sync on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, fstream

Re this quetion: [Does close() call fsync() on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348431/does-close-call-fsync-on-linux)

This question describes that close() (c lib) does not call sync on linux.

Is this the same for fstream::close()?:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/close/ suggests that is does write all the remaining bytes to file. I have observed (rare) cases where I finish writing a block of 2-3KB to a file, call fs.close() and then try to open it and the open fails. Adding a short delay and/or calling sync seems to cure this.

So I think I have answered my own question, but the std::fstream::close() description confuses me

Comment: AFAIK `sync` should not affect this.  I think you should look elsewhere for the cause of your problems.

Comment: What do you mean opening fails? Fails how? `fsync` has nothing to do with flushing data to a file, but causes writing data to an underlying device.

Comment: @StaceyGirl fails like: `std::ifstream ifs {filename, in | binary}; if (!ifs) {...fail...}` I run this right after I closed it having written all the data.

Comment: @code_fodder It should not fail. Whatever you are doing, it has nothing to do with `sync`, `fsync` etc. Unless it involves some faulty network storage or running under Linux Subsystem for Windows or something like that.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I saw this once on an ubuntu VM, but mostly I see this running on linux in a jenkins test environment. But its rare. All I am really doing is writing to an ofstream and reading back using ifstream - simple stuff. The answers below suggest it *could* be an issue...

Comment: @code_fodder None of 2 answers suggest that. Regardless of whether data is on device or not, the OS has to maintain the same view of filesystem e.g. caching is transparent.

Comment: @StaceyGirl... hmm, then I am at a loss as to what is going on here... :(

Comment: @StaceyGirl also calling sync does fix it ... empirical evidence?

Comment: @code_fodder I think `sync` will work just as good as `usleep`.

Comment: @StaceyGirl do you have a theory why any delay might be needed? - other then memory types. This is running on a desktop PC SSD - flash mem?

Comment: @code_fodder You are mistakenly assuming that filesystem view has anything to do with physical device - it doesn't. Opening, reading, writing doesn't even touch the device most of the time, instead it gets information from a RAM (file cache). So `fsync` should not have any visible side aside from preserving your data after power loss.

Comment: @StaceyGirl well, I won't argue with you there, but I can just point to my evidence... I have not printed the code, but its really simple ifstream ofstream code. I know the data is 100% correct because its binary files that I can binary compare and even execute. I have written files from a few bytes to 100's MB with no data corruption of any sort. I cant think of anything unusual then re-opening the file right away (which is generally an uncommon thing to do). So I think the answers below do answer *this* qusetion, I am thinking my issue is a slightly different question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does ofstream::close() call sync ...

It will flush the buffers that are internal to the stream, and the closes it. Whether something comparable to `sync` or `fsync` is called is unpecified.

> ... on linux?

This is up to the implementation. Thus, it may depend on which standard library implementation you use. If you use an open source one, you can take a look at the source to see what it does.

Comment: I am using the gcc libs on ubuntu. I don't think I have the source available there, but I am sure I can look that up, thanks : )

Comment: @code_fodder The sources are in the gcc-${version}-source package. They are also in several publicly accessible repositories on the internet.

Comment: I had a look in the source. It does call its own "sync()" function, but that just finishes off writing to the file (as far as I can tell - not that great at reading the std libs). So I do not think it does a sync at os level. Thanks for the hint for the source code :)

Answer (score 3):

It might depend on the library implementation, but for common ones, it does not. What is written in ccpreference, means that the *internal stream buffer* writes any pending bytes before closing. But it does not request the os file system driver to force an immediate write on the disk device.

Comment: ah, ok - that makes sense - it sounds similar to c style close() then - I guess they are roughly the same under the hood.  So if you are writing to a file and close it and you know you want to read again from it immediately calling the linux OS sync might be required?

Comment: @code_fodder: It should not be required. After closing a file you should be able to re-open it immediately. If you experience a problem there, it is in fact a quite different question.

Comment: yes I just realised that (and commented in the main comment block) as you say, this Question has an answer  thanks : )